# How to search a directory for files with specific name and make list using JAVA

Tags: java

I'm really new to programming so please be patient with me. I've searched the net and couldn't find a post specific to what I need done. I need to take a text list of file names (I do not have the extension of the file, it should be .sgm .xml.pdf) and search a directory and all its sub-directories for a file name match. If the match is found it should output the directory location then move on to the next file name.

The code below doesn't search the subdirectory.

````
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.List;

 
/**
 * Class takes a text file and searches a directory for matching file names and outputs a new file with the paths of found directories.
 * 
 * @author Rishal
 *
 */
public class CheckFileNames {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 

        // Path of the file which is having all the names of the files
        String list = "C:\\Test\\AF IPT Search\\Test_FileNames.txt";
        List listOfFileNamesToCheck = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(list), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
 
        // Input object to get input from the user
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 
        // Reading source and destination from the user
        System.out.println("Enter Source folder path:");
        String sourceFolder = br.readLine();
 
 
        // getting list of all the files present in the source folder
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
 
        // Looping into each fileNames present in the listOfFiles.txt to check
        // if its present in the source folder
        for (String loopInFileNames : listOfFileNamesToCheck) {
            for (File file : fList) { // looping into the Source Folder
                                        // fileNames
 
                // Matching the fileNames in the sourceFolder and list of files
                // supplied by the user.
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().equals(loopInFileNames)) {
                    // Copying the file into the target folder.
                    System.out.println(file.getName())).toPath());
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(loopInFileNames + " :Files Copied Succesfully!");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: in the for loop you are handling the case for files (if file.isFile() ..) part, you should add another condition for the case when it isn't a file and is a directory

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: He means you need to go into the directory in your `for` if your `if` is false and the current object is a directory.